# Can you import a python module from another directory in a github repo?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a github repo consisting of python files/modules which looks like this.

```
Folder1 >>> file_to_import + Folder2 
Folder2 >>> more_files
```

Can I directly import the `file_to_import` into folder 2's `more_files` using python's command

```
import file_to_import
```

If not what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
import ../filesToImport
```

that should work

Comment: ../ Does this mean I have to mention the full path?

Comment: No ../ means one directory back

Comment: Thank you! Suppose if I want to go two directories back can I use `../` twice?

Comment: Yes that would work like this: ../../

Comment: I am trying to import a package but i keep getting Unresolved reference 'pytorch_grad_cam'